# Jquery append text data with a line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this script which takes the data from a form and append it in to a HTML div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    div {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    input[type=text],
    textarea,
    select {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    input[type=button] {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: auto;
      float: right;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 7px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>


    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="selCountry">
        <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="bt" value="Write" onclick="writeFile()" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="output-area">
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <div id="output" class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span></span>

</body>
<script>
  let writeFile = () => {

    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');

    let data =
      'Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n ' +  
      'Age: ' + age.value + ' \r\n ' +  
      'Email: ' + email.value + ' \r\n ' +  
      'Country: ' + country.value + ' \r\n ' +  
      'Message: ' + msg.value;


    $('#output').append("<br />" + "<br />");
    $('#output').append(document.createTextNode(data));

  }
</script>

</html>
```

But the issue is when I fill the data and click on `Write` it outputs all of the form data in a single line. (Name: x Age: 4 Email: y Country: Japan Message: z)

And I want it to be like this,

```
Name: x 
Age: 4 
Email: y 
Country: Japan 
Message: z

Name: x 
Age: 42
Email: y 
Country: Japan 
Message: zd ....
```

So I tried to create a new line (\n) using javascript but seems like it doesn't affect it.

This is what I've tried.

```
          'Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n ' + '\n' +   
          'Age: ' + age.value + ' \r\n ' + '\n' +     
          'Email: ' + email.value + ' \r\n ' + '\n' +     
          'Country: ' + country.value + ' \r\n ' + '\n' +     
          'Message: ' + msg.value;
```

So what's the issue here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Line breaks don't have a meaning in HTML. You need to use the `<br />` tag instead - or wrap each line in a `<p>` tag

Comment: You could wrap the data in a **<pre>** tag, which would enable the CRLFs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    div {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    input[type=text],
    textarea,
    select {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    input[type=button] {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: auto;
      float: right;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 7px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>


    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="selCountry">
        <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="bt" value="Write" onclick="writeFile()" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="output-area">
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <div id="output" class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span></span>

</body>
<script>
  let writeFile = () => {

    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');

    let data = [ 
      `<p>Name: ${name.value}</p>`, 
      `<p>Age: ${age.value}</p>`, 
      `<p>Email: ${email.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Country: ${country.value}</p>`,  
      `<p>Message: ${msg.value}</p>`];
 
   
    $('#output').append("<br />" + "<br />");

    data.forEach(line => $('#output').append(line));

  }
</script>

</html>
```

So here I am first putting each line of data into a `<p>` tag and then putting that in a list, I am using template literals which are just cleaner. Then to insert the data you want to call a `.forEach()` on the list and then add each line (or item of the list) to the output. Below is the part I changed.

```
let data = [ 
  `<p>Name: ${name.value}</p>`, 
  `<p>Age: ${age.value}</p>`, 
  `<p>Email: ${email.value}</p>`,  
  `<p>Country: ${country.value}</p>`,  
  `<p>Message: ${msg.value}</p>`];
 
   
$('#output').append("<br />" + "<br />");
data.forEach(line => $('#output').append(line));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always just wrap the output in a `<pre>` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    div {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    input[type=text],
    textarea,
    select {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    input[type=button] {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: auto;
      float: right;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 7px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>


    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="selCountry">
        <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" id="bt" value="Write" onclick="writeFile()" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="output-area">
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <div id="output" class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span></span>

</body>
<script>
  let writeFile = () => {

    const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
    const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
    const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
    const msg = document.getElementById('msg');

    let data = 'Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n' +  
      'Age: ' + age.value + ' \r\n' +  
      'Email: ' + email.value + ' \r\n' +  
      'Country: ' + country.value + ' \r\n' +  
      'Message: ' + msg.value;


    //$('#output').append("<br />" + "<br />");
    $('#output').append(`<pre>${data}</pre>`);


  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to break the line in HTML, you want to use `<br>` instead of `\r\n`. For example like this:

```
let data =
  'Name: ' + name.value + '<br>' +
  'Age: ' + age.value + '<br>' +
  'Email: ' + email.value + '<br>' +
  'Country: ' + country.value + '<br>' +
  'Message: ' + msg.value;
```

Then if you are appending HTML, don't use `createTextNode()` function, since it would escape HTML entities. So you can simply use:

```
$('#output').append(data);
```

And the last thing. If you don't want to append the content every time you hit the button, you can enter data into DIV using `html()` function, instead `append()`.

```
$('#output').html(data);
```